# Does Interface Requestor in com.solacesystems.jcsmp work with DTO=false?

Tags: solace

Even though I called BytesXMLMessage.setDeliverToOne(false), I noticed that Requestor.request(XMLMessage request, long timeoutMillis, Destination sendDestination) will just return immediately when a reply is received from any one of the producers.  I just wonder how I can wait for all producers to reply.

Answer (score 0):

`Requestor.request()` is used for a single request and reply, and is expected to return after the first reply message is received.

You will need to implement your own logic to receive multiple replies to a single request.

You can do this by doing something like the following:

1. Subscribe to a well-known topic for replies.
2. Publish the request message, with the reply-to field set to the well-known reply topic.
3. Receive replies on the well-known reply topic that you have subscribed to in (1).